# Can I prove I only played solo?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that I can create a hero and only play solo 100% of the time in diablo 3.

My question is this: Can I and other people see that my hero ONLY played solo all the time and never joined a public game?

I'm asking this because I want to create a hero and only play solo and I like to take credit for all my achievements, but if it's not shown that I played solo ALL the time, then it's kinda pointless.

And if it's account-wide, it's not an issue for me. I like to create a new account to create one single hero for this purpose.

Comment: I don't think you can see that anywhere but I'm not 100% sure. You can see the highest solo GRIFT runs though AFAIK and that's pretty much the endgame.

Comment: Maybe by the achievements ? But that's Account wide.

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing that indicates if you have played with others or not, aside from a few achievements that can only be unlocked while playing with others.

Comment: I suggest to rename to "*Can I prove I only played solo?*" I first thought the question is about online status or something.

Comment: "if it's not shown that I played solo ALL the time, then it's kinda pointless" Isn't it enough that *you* know this to be true?

Comment: Jasper, it's not enough that only I know it's true.

Comment: I doubt anyone would care about achieved you solo or in group something (e.g. Diablo kill?). There **are** already achievements to prove your personal skills, they specifically stating "not in a group". But there are also achievements which require group, it's plain stupid to skip those to prove something to likely no-one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is one way to "prove" you have never played with other players but it requires either a new account or an account that hasn't played cooperative games yet.

Generally speaking you can prove it by **having your cooperative achievement list empty**. There are achievements like [**Heroes of the ages**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Heroes_of_the_Ages) which trigger on joining a coop game. Also there are achievements that just "happen" in a coop game like [**Bloodletting**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Bloodletting) for example.

Since achievements are account wide and not character specific, there isn't really a way to prove it otherwise.

The only other thing I could think of which wouldn't require a new account would be recording/streaming every bit of progress on a specific character.

**Note that a new account means you have to buy a new copy of the game.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I create a new account and a hero that only play solo, then the achievement 'Heroes of ages' never occur, then I can prove that my account/hero has NEVER joined a multi-player game. Correct?

Comment: @OlePetersen Should be the case yes. I'm not sure if opening a game to the public ignores this achievement but there are some other Achievements that just "happen" in cooperative games. [**Bloodletting**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Bloodletting) for example. Generally speaking: If your Coop achievement list is empty you can prove it.

Comment: @simbabque unfortunately yes. It might be possible to reset an account somehow with the help of Blizzard support but I'm not when they'd do that.

Comment: @simbabque yeah I updated the answer (also with additional information that was in the comments before)

Comment: Couldn't someone play a seasonal character and use the seasonal achievements to prove they've solo'd. Up until the point the season ends though and assuming all their characters for that seasons are solo characters.